# Shell script string search where '#' is not in 1st character position

Tags: shell, find, grep, xargs

this string search was provided by Paul.R (much appreciated Paul):

**  find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -F -f strings.txt  **

Note, I am using the above search argument to perform a recursive directory search for hard coded path names within shell scripts.  However, due to the limitations of the Unix environment (TRU64) I am unable to use the GREP -r switch to perform my directory search.  Hence the use of the solution provided above.

As an additional criteria, I would like to extend this search argument to exclude any text where the first leading character of the string being searched is "#" (comment symbol).

Would appreciate any feedback.

Thanks...Evan

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're just trying to limit the results in the output from the command you posted.  If that's so, then how about

find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -F -f strings.txt | grep -v '^#'

The final piped command will ignore all lines that match the regex ^# (begins with # char)

Comment: Patrick, thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, this does not quite do it. The original command I posted outputs the path name and file the string belongs to starting in the first character position. I need this to identify the scripts that satisfy my search criteria. If I grep the result set the comment symbol can exist in any character position. I realise I can in this instance omit the '^' symbol, however, how do I distinguish the use of '#' as part of a comment, rather than a character on any part of that line?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is first filter out all lines that have a comment starting in position 1 of all scripts, then feed that result set into searching for path names within those scripts.

Comment: 1. In order to filter out data where the hash acts to signal a comment but not where the hash acts as a character means you're going to have to figure out what, in the code, signals that the hash is acting as a character literal.  

2. is this command for a one-off project (where we could make multiple passes) or is it for use for some other purpose?  I had to mangle your original post a little, but does this help (you can reinsert your second grep to get the functionality i removed
 -- 
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat | grep -v '^[ \t]*#' | grep -v ^$ -- that should get you started

Answer (score 0):

This solution will not work if the path and file of the files is contained in strings.txt, but it might work in your situation.

```
find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -v '^#' | grep -F -f strings.txt
```